# String format not displaying properly in label text

Tags: string, vb.net, string-formatting

I'm trying to format a list of string in order to display items into two columns with a length of 40 each one. For that, I'm using next function:

```
Private Function GetNamesString(names As List(Of String)) As String
    Dim str As String = String.Empty
    For i = 0 To names.Count - 2 Step 2
        str += $"{names(i),-40}{names(i + 1),-40}"
        str += $"{vbCrLf}"
    Next
    Return str
End Function
```

I build up the message as next:

```
Dim message As String = $"Removing master species {gbl.EditSpecies.Name} implies that next {names.Count} species must be also removed:{vbCrLf}{vbCrLf}"
message += GetNamesString(names)
message += $"{vbCrLf}{vbCrLf}Do you want to remove above species besides {gbl.EditSpecies.Name}?"
```

Getting next string:

```
Removing master species Fe+3 implies that next 106 species must be also removed:

Beidellite_SBld-1(4.576H2O)             Ca2Fe2O5(s)                             
CaFe2O4(s)                              C4FH13                                  
C3FH6                                   Ettringite-Fe                           
Monosulfate-Fe                          Smectite_MX80(5.189H2O)                 
...
```

Finally, I display the message form:

```
frmShowMessage.Show(message, "Remove species", enumMessageIcon.Warning, enumMessageButton.YesNo)
```

The `message` is displayed in the label text directly:       `lblMessageText.Text = message` (font type used for label text is Arial).

However, I get next result:

[image]

Which is not displayed in column formats as I want. Do you know why I'm getting unformatted string in message form?

Thank you!

Comment: from what I can tell you're simply adding 40 spaces after the end of each string? You need to take into account the actual length of each item and subtract that from the 40. Or the sensible thing might be to just use a data grid (or other control which is designed to display things in a table-like layout).

Comment: If you expect text to align using that method then you have to use a fixed-width font.

Comment: So which font may I use?

Comment: What exactly is preventing you from finding out for yourself? This site is for the hard stuff you can't work out for yourself, not the stuff you couldn't be bothered to search for.

Comment: @ADyson, it's not just adding 40 spaces. It's padding each text value to 40 characters with trailing spaces. The subtraction you suggest is happening automatically.

Comment: @ADyson As far as I know, the string format I'm using (i.e. $"{str,-40}") is giving you a 40 length column adding as extra spaces as needed.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thanks for the clarification, didn't know that.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Ok, I edited mi question now. I'm using Arial font type which I believe is fixed-width, am I right? Still getting same issue...

Comment: No, Arial is not fixed-width.

Comment: Fixed width means each letter occupies the same width. You clearly can see that Beidellite (10 chars) is wayyy smaller than CaFe2O4(s) (10 chars also). Fixed width is the font you used to write the question.

Comment: I see, I fixed it using either Consolas or Courier. I wasn't aware of that. Thank you all! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jmcilhinney pointed out on the question comments, I was using a proportional font (e.g., Arial font type) which is impossible to fit it right into equally spaced columns.

The solution is to use a monospaced font type (e.g., Consolas):

[image]